# Apache redirect 301 parent directory don't work

Tags: apache-httpd

I need to redirect 2 similar path to same webpage, es

http://www.domain.com/foo --> http://www.domain.com/ok

http://www.domain.com/foo/bar --> http://www.domain.com/ok

I have this in .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /foo http://www.domain.com/ok
Redirect 301 /foo/bar http://www.domain.com/ok
```

If I go to http://www.domain.com/foo the redirect works, if I go to http://www.domain.com/foo/bar, I have http://www.domain.com/ok/bar and it doesn't work.
How can resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Try change order:

```
Redirect 301 /foo/bar http://www.domain.com/ok
Redirect 301 /foo http://www.domain.com/ok
```

Also look at mod_rewrite:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html

```
#With mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/docs/(.+)  http://new.example.com/docs/$1  [R,L]

#With RedirectMatch
RedirectMatch ^/docs/(.*) http://new.example.com/docs/$1

#With Redirect
Redirect /docs/ http://new.example.com/docs/
```

Comment: Good, works! I have change order, thanks!